# Problemas com conexão à API do Bing Ads

Tags: r, api

Estou criando uma conexão à API do Bing Ads via R, pois não existe uma biblioteca para tal e preciso obter todos os dados *analytics* existentes para o meu projeto.

Porém não estou conseguindo realizar esta conexão via *POSTMAN* para realizar testes. Sempre que eu tento fazer, ele pede para abrir o navegador para permitir o acesso e eu gostaria de saber se é possível realizar uma conexão direta ou terei de fazer esse direcionamento para o navegador, já que eu irei automatizar essa conexão no meu servidor.

[image]

Comment: A API pede autenticação (OAuth)?

Comment: @TomásBarcellos Eles ordenam que a autenticação seja feita através desta URL de autorização para obter o _code_ para utilizar em outra URL para autenticar o usuário e poder realizar as requisições com o _token_ gerado.

Não é possível realizar com o _OAuth_ do _POSTMAN_, por exemplo.

Mais em: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bing-ads-user-authentication-oauth-guide.aspx